# Include HTML file in Angular unit testing code coverage report

Tags: angular, jasmine, istanbul, karma-coverage

I am using Angular 6 with karma coverage istanbul reporter to see code coverage.

It show only .ts file in the code coverage report which could be misleading as HTML templates can also include code logic.

Is there anyway to include HTML code to unit test code coverage?